# How can I detect if my radio is listed in streaming directory

Tags: icecast

I have an icecast server and want to learn if my radio is listed in yp directory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. Icecast docs say:

> After adjusting the settings and configuring your source client, you
>   should verify setup:   Go to the Icecast web interface, specifically
>   the admin part /admin/ and look for the listenurl values of your
>   streams. These URLs MUST work from the public internet, or your
>   listings will fail.